# what are the prerequisites for cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am a beginner in aws and my mentor told me to learn cloudformation so, my exact question is how to start cloudformation and where to start this and what are the prerequisites for cloudformation..?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the right question to ask here. You can simply search it on Google and Youtube, But as you asked, I will give you a few Headstarts or context.

Cloudformation Template Contains 3 Main Things/Sections.

1. Parameters
2. Resources
3. Output

Now to write all these 3 things, you should know Json or Yaml Language. AWS Cloudformation Service supports both Yaml and JSON.

The main thing is to focus on here is CloudFormation Template is **IaaC** [Infrastructure as a Code]. It means we are creating Infrastructure [or say **resources**] by writing code.
So in the end we are creating AWS resources such as EC2 or VPC or Security Group or name any other services.

So your Template should include **Resources**. If it does not have a Parameter or Output section, it will still run successfully. But again it depends on your use case.

Now you have to understand what are these Parameters and Output.

For example, you are creating an EC2 Server. So, your high-level cloud formation template will look like *[It is not the exact code, for sake of your initial understanding I am writing in this way and using YAML]*:

1. Parameter: As you are creating EC2 and you want to name your EC2 Server. So this parameter Section you will ask for input from the user who is executing this template.

   ```
   Parameter:
    MyEC2Name:
     Description: "Enter the EC2 Name"
     Type: String
   ```
2. Resources: It is the section where you actually write code to create EC2

   ```
   Resources:
    MyEC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
     Tags:
       -Key: "Name"
        Value: !Ref MyEC2Name
        ....
   ```

In the last line of code **Value:!Ref MyEC2Name** you can see that we are using the input which we asked in Parameter Section. So your template will create an EC2 with the name you specified while executing this template.

3. Output: For example, you want to show something after the completion of your template. Maybe the Unique Id of EC2 or anything such as your name or any other info; you can pass it in Output Section

   ```
    Output:
     MyName:
     Value: "Bhavuk"
   ```

That is what Cloud Formation Template looks like and you can modify it as per your need. I believe after reading this, you can go through any Link or Blog or any video; you can understand the Context. Because before starting anything new, you have to understand what it does and its exact purpose. In Starting it may look scary. But I know after few days you will be reading an advanced topic on it. Happy Learning :).

If you have any doubt, let me know at bhavukbhardwaj03@gmail.com as I can understand the pain, which I felt years back.

Here are some links to start:[Link](https://medium.com/cloud-security/easier-aws-cloudformation-47a30c631963)

Also, [Official AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html)